# Существует ли способ просмотра log Node.js сервера?!

Tags: node.js

Мне очень необходимо посмотреть кто обращается к моему Node.js серверу (IP пользователя, на какой порт итд.), существует ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите на компоненты для Node.js на этой странице: [Logging and dumping](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-logs).

Чтобы отследить ip пользователя при подключению к серверу, можно использовать событие `connection`

```
server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('Client adress is: ' + socket.remoteAddress);
});
```